# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings in a referenced assembly

Tags: c#, configuration-files

I have a command line utility app designed for making server backups. I've also got a GUI app that gives access to various maintenance functions, including the ability to make server backups. Previously, this app duplicated the backup code, which was causing consistency and maintainability issues. I'm in the process of refactoring the GUI app to reference the command line app and call its backup methods instead, in the name of code reuse.

I've just run into a problem, though - the command line app has a config file, read using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`. When it's called directly, that works fine. When it's called as a reference from the GUI app, though, it tries to read the GUI app's config file instead, as the executing assembly, and throws an error when it can't find the values it expects.

How can I force the code to always read the command line app's config file, even when it's not actually the executing assembly?

Answer (score 1):

Just set AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", path);

Comment: I don't understand AppDomains as well as I should - will that not cause problems if the GUI app wants to read its own config?

Comment: And that won't cause problems if the GUI app calls the command line functions, remaps the config file address, and then subsequently wants to read its own config?